# Beamer: How to change the aspect ratio of the width of two columns of header?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

My professor has given me his custom made beamer template for making presentation slides. However, I have ran into a problem which I can't solve. The header of my slides have two column. The first column contains the name of sections and the second column contains the name of subsections. But the name of one of my section is too big to fit in the first column and that can be seen hear:[image]

**Now, I am thinking that if somehow I can decrease the width of the second column and increase the width of the first column then my section's and subsection's name would fit in their respective columns. I think it can be done because I have readjusted the width of the two column of footline using the following code:**

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.30\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor%~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.70\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

I am sharing the download link of my [beamer template.](https://github.com/PowerUnlock/Beamer_Template/archive/refs/heads/main.zip)
Please download the zip-folder and compile the file **document.tex** given in it.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post only code fragments. Always include a small, but compilable test file in your questions.

Comment: Welcome! My advice is to use a shorter title (or add a short version). Like `\section[New construction method]{New construction method with a lot of information which is better to put in a paragraph and not in a title}`) 

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the headline like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hyderabad}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  {\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionnavigation{.7\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionnavigation{.3\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  }%
  \vskip0pt
  \begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-4pt}}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{4pt}}%
    \pgfsetfading{beamer@topshadowmask}{}%
    \pgfusepath{fill}%
  \end{pgfpicture}
  \vskip-2pt
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Overview}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]